# Evaluate $\int_\gamma \frac{-y \ dx +x \ dy}{x^2+y^2}$ by interpretation

Tags: integration

I am working on the following exercise:

> For $0 \le t \le 2\pi$ consider the curve
>
> $$\gamma(t)=\begin{pmatrix}x(t)\\ y(t)\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}\sin(3t)\\\cos(5t)\end{pmatrix}.$$
>
> Evaluate the line integral $$\int_\gamma \frac{-y \ dx +x \ dy}{x^2+y^2}$$
>
> by a suitable interpretaion and counting alone, without integration.

I do not see how I should interpret this. Could you help me?

Comment: Seems like that the curve should be pictured and the winding number should be counted to get the integral. However the curve is not a Jordan curve… seems complicated.

Comment: Plot the curve and apply the [Alexander numbering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winding_number#Alexander_numbering).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is about [Ampere's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amp%C3%A8re%27s_circuital_law). We can get the magnetic field due to an infinite wire coincident with the $z$-axis carrying constant current $I$ in the +$z$=direction because of the symmetries of the problem. When the current distribution is reflected through a plane, the components of the magnetic field $\vec B$ at a point in the plane parallel to the plane are reversed while the normal component stays the same. The magnetic field is an axial vector which means that it rotates like a vector like the electric field $\vec E$ under proper rotations but inversion of coordinates through a point don't change the $\vec B$ field at that point whereas they reverse $\vec E$. The reason for this is that $\vec E=\frac{q\hat r}{4\pi\epsilon_0r^2}$ by [Coulomb's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coulomb%27s_law) where $\vec r$ is the vector from the source point to the field point, $r$ is its magnitude, $\hat r=\frac{\vec r}r$, $q$ is the charge and $\epsilon_0$ is a constant. Thus under inversion, $\hat r$ and so $\vec E$ gets reversed. The [Biot-Savart law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biot%E2%80%93Savart_law) says $\vec B=\frac{\mu_0\vec v\times\hat r}{4\pi r^2}$ where now $\vec v$ is the velocity of the charge and $\mu_0$ is another constant. Under inversion, $\hat r$ gets reversed, but so does $\vec v$ so $\vec B$ is unchanged. Since reflection through a plane is an improper rotation, the result for the $\vec B$ field is exactly the opposite of what happens to the $\vec E$ field where the in-plane components are unchanged and the normal component is reversed.

Thus we are up to $\vec B=B(r,\phi,z)\langle-\sin\phi,\cos\phi,0\rangle$. The magnitude of $\vec B$ can't depend on $z$, however, because if the field point is moved up or down the current distribution is the same because the wire has infinite extent in the $z$-direction. Also it can't depend on $\phi$ because of the rotational symmetry of the problem: $B(r,\phi,z)=B(r)$ only. Thus we can set up a loop $\vec r=\langle r\cos\phi,r\sin\phi,0\rangle$ for $0\le\phi\le2\pi$, $d\vec r=\langle-r\sin\phi,r\cos\phi,0\rangle\,d\phi$ and integrate Ampere's law:
$$\begin{align}\oint_C\vec B\cdot d\vec r&=\int_0^{3\pi}B(r)\langle-\sin\phi,\cos\phi,0\rangle\cdot \langle-r\sin\phi,r\cos\phi,0\rangle\,d\phi\\
&=rB(r)\int_0^{2\pi}d\phi=2\pi rB(r)\\
&=\mu_0I_{enc}=\mu_0I\end{align}$$
And so we have
$$\vec B=\frac{\mu_0I}{2\pi r}\langle-\sin\phi,\cos\phi,0\rangle=\frac{\mu_0I}{2\pi(x^2+y^2)}\langle-y,x,0\rangle$$
So the statement of the problem is to find
$$\frac{2\pi}{\mu_0I}\oint_{\gamma}\vec B\cdot\,d\vec r=\frac{2\pi}{\mu_0I}\cdot\mu_0I_{enc}$$
Around the path $\vec r=\langle\sin3t\cos5t,0\rangle$. For this path the $x$-period is $2\pi/3$ and the $y$-period is $2\pi/5$ and their least common multiple is $2\pi$. We can find $i_{enc}$ by counting: every time the curve crosses the +$y$-axis so $x=0$ if $x$ is decreasing we are going counterclockwise so that is a positive loop around the wire on the $z$-axis while if $x$ is increasing we are going clockwise so that is a negative loop.

We cross the $y$-axis for $t\in\{0,\pi/3,2\pi/3\,\pi,4\pi/3,5\pi/3\}$. For $t\in\{2\pi/3,\pi,4\pi/3\}$, $y=\cos5t<0$ so those are crossing of the negative $y$-axis and don't count. For $t\in\{\pi/3,5\pi/3\}$, $\frac{dx}{dt}=3\cos3t<0$, so those are positive windings, but for $t=0$, $\frac{dx}{dt}>0$, a negative winding. Thus $I_{enc}=(2-1)I=I$ and so
$$\oint_{\gamma}\frac{\langle-y,x,0\rangle}{x^2+y^2}\cdot d\vec r=2\pi$$
So we used interpretation of Ampere's law and the only integral we actually did was the trivial integral
$$\int_0^{2\pi}d\phi=2\pi$$
necessary to derive the magnitude of the magnetic field due to an infinite wire. Most of the work was to repeat the proof of the magnetic field of an infinite wire. Remember how hard we worked in Physics II?

**EDIT**: Here is the Lissajous figure. I have drawn green arrows for counterclockwise encirclements and red arrows for clockwise.
[image: fig 1]

Answer (score 1):

The one of the approach is
$$\begin{align}&\int{\left( \frac{xdy-ydx}{x^2+y^2} \right)} \\
=&\int{\left( \left( \frac{1}{1+\left( \frac{y}{x} \right) ^2} \right) \left( \frac{xdy-ydx}{x^2} \right) \right)}\\
=&\int{\left( \frac{d\left( \frac{y}{x} \right)}{1+\left( \frac{y}{x} \right) ^2} \right)} \\
=&\tan ^{-1}\left( \frac{y}{x} \right) +C\end{align}$$

Comment: It's possible to do it this way, but you have to sum the jumps of $\arctan(y/x)$ on the $y$-axis (the advantage is that this can be done algebraically without plotting the curve).

Answer (score 1):

Let $z=\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}t}$, $w=x+\mathrm{i}y$. Then the integral in question is
$$\begin{split}\Im \int_{\lvert z \rvert =1}\frac{\mathrm{d}w}{w}&=
\Im\int_{\lvert z \rvert =1}\frac{\mathrm{d}(z^5+z^{-5}-(z^3-z^{-3}))}{z^5+z^{-5}-(z^3-z^{-3})}\\
&=\Im\int_{\lvert z \rvert =1}\left(\frac{\mathrm{d}z^{-5}}{z^{-5}} +\frac{\mathrm{d}(z^{10}-z^8 +z^2+1)}{z^{10}-z^8 +z^2+1}\right)\\
&=(2\pi)\left(-5+\frac{2\Im}{2\pi}\int_{\lvert z \rvert =1}\frac{\mathrm{d}(z^{5}-z^4 +z+1)}{z^{5}-z^4 +z+1}\right)\\
&=(2\pi)\left(-5+\frac{2\Im}{2\pi}\int_{\lvert z \rvert =1}\frac{f'(z)\mathrm{d}z}{f(z)}\right)
\end{split}$$
where $$f(z)=z^5 -z^4+z+1\text{.}$$ By the residue calculus,

$$\frac{\Im}{2\pi}\int_{\lvert z \rvert =1}\frac{f'(z)\mathrm{d}z}{f(z)}=N_f$$
where $N_f$ is the number of zeros of the polynomial $f$ lying inside the unit complex disk. But we know that
$$\Im \int_{\lvert z \rvert =1}\frac{\mathrm{d}w}{w}=2\pi N$$
where $N$ is the winding number of the original closed curve about the origin. Thus
$$\boxed{N=-5+2N_f}\text{.}$$

But what is $N_f$? Take the [Cayley transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley_transform#Complex_homography) of $f$: 
$$\begin{align}
z&=\frac{1+\mathrm{i}v}{1-\mathrm{i}v} &
f(z)&=(1-\mathrm{i}v)^{-5}2\mathrm{i} h(\mathrm{i}v)\text{.}\end{align}$$
We want to find the number of zeros of the polynomial $h(w)$ in the left half-plane, where
$$\mathrm{i}h(w)=1-w+10w^2+2w^3+5w^4+w^5\text{.}$$
We apply the [Routh–Hurwitz theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Routh%E2%80%93Hurwitz_theorem). Write $h$ as
$$\begin{align} h(\mathrm{i}v)&=P_0(v)+\mathrm{i}P_1(v)\\
P_0(v)&=v^5-2v^3-3v \\
P_1(v)&=-5v^4+10v^2-1\text{.}\end{align}$$

Then we construct the associated Sturm sequence
$$\begin{align}
5P_0+vP_1&=-P_2&P_2&=16v\\
16P_1+(5v^3-10v)P_2&=-P_3&P_3&=16
\end{align}$$

So that we have a sign table
$$\begin{align} &i && \mathrm{sgn}\,P_i(\infty) &&\mathrm{sgn}\,P_i(-\infty) \\
&0 && + && - \\
&1 && - && - \\
&2 && + && - \\
&3 && + && + \\
\end{align}$$
There are two sign changes in the left column and one in the right column. Therefore there is one more root of $h$ in the left half-plane than in the right half-plane. Thus $N_f=1$, and the winding number of the original curve is $N=1$, and the original integral has value 
$$\boxed{2\pi}\text{.}$$